# 403 Forbidden for OpenApiSwagger in Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have Spring Boot application with Spring Security. After configure configuration-class localhost-Swagger return 403 Forbidden. I can't figure out what could be the problem.

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/ - 403 Forbidden

SecurityConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                           .antMatchers("/api/user/auth")
                           .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs")
                           .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
                           .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
                           .antMatchers("/configuration/**")
                           .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
                           .antMatchers("/public");
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.7.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.7.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.7.2'

    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '9.4.1.jre16'

    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20220320'

    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.9'

    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
}
```

P.S. Please do not suggest to inherit the class from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as it is deprecated in my version of Spring Security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/swagger-ui/**` instead of `/swagger-ui.html` in web security configuration:

```java
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                       .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                       .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**")
                       .antMatchers("configuration/**")
                       .antMatchers("/swagger*/**")
                       .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
                       .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**");
}
```

Did you put `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` in your application property file?